# How to do Numpy Logic Operation in OpenCV Mat object C++

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv

In python I have a function that saturates values stored in an image

```
def saturateData(minMax, img):
    alpB = cal_alpB(minMax)
    img[img>minMax[1]] = minMax[1]
    img[img<0] = 0
```

where `minMax` is a list stores the saturation values to be applied on an image numpy array. I need to do the same operation at a `cv::Mat` object.

Is there any function that does the same operation. If not how can I achieve this? (since I am working with the images I have to it fast, the function I wrote is O(N^2) which is inefficient that's why I am asking this question!)

Comment: Use `np.clip` ?

Comment: I can achieve this in python pretty easily, I need the same solution in cv::Mat object C++

Comment: look at [`cv::threshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d8e/tutorial_threshold.html)

Comment: OpenCV's `cv::Mat` has a `.setTo()` method. it takes a scalar value and a mask argument. you calculate the mask using `cv::compare` (or a "matrix expression", like in python with numpy). you don't need cv::threshold.

Comment: I have calculated the mask input, yet I don't what should I use in the scalar value. Can you help please?